# HTML: Disable Click in a cell of a table

Tags: html

i have a calendar formed table. and i was wondering how can i disable all the clicks under that cell. because my argument would be. anything less than the current date will be disable. **meaning all click functions of all the child of the td on that dates will be disabled (add, edit, view list)**

can you help me out. i cant give any code. coz is quite unorganized at this moment.

hope you can give me an idea.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the event handler of your click event, you can prevent link following by returning false.

Super simplified:

```
function myClickHandler(e)
{
    var target = e.srcElement;
    if (!target)
        target = e.target;

    var sdate = new Date(target.parent.getAttribute("rel"));
    if (sdate < currentdate) // doesn't take into account time!!
        return false;
}
```

Given the following markup:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="day" rel="1/1/2010">
                <a href="edit" onclick="return myClickHandler(e)">Edit this day</a>
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. maybe this will disable the td's click.. but not the child of the td

Comment: Sorry, you have to return the value of the function. Edited to correct.